# Tensorflow not detecting GPU after i installed cuda and cudnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

I have been trying to get tensorflow to detect and use my gpu. I have installed cuda and cudnn drivers but get this everytime I import tensorflow.

```
2023-08-30 22:15:57.164247: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:110] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2023-08-30 22:15:57.165481: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-08-30 22:15:57.192695: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-08-30 22:15:57.193290: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-08-30 22:15:57.684009: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
```

and when I run tf.config.list_physical_devices() I get this:

```
2023-08-30 22:16:22.131423: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:995] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
2023-08-30 22:16:22.200600: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1960] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

I have a RTX 3060 ti. I am using a miniconda environment on a ubuntu 22.04 OS. I am using tensorflow version 2.13. I have installed CUDA version 11.8 using the guide provided by nvidia. I have installed Cudnn version 8.6.0.163 also using the nvidia guide. Followed the guide and commands provided in the tensorflow documentation.

And I'm still getting this issue.

Comment: did you install the nvidia drivers? (not cuda or cudnn). Does your GPU show up in nvidia-smi?

Comment: Yes I have installed the nvidia drivers version 535 and my gpu does show up when i run nvidia-smi

Comment: nvidia-smi works here also, cuda and cudnn are installed as per the recommended versions but tensorflow reports no gpu present, when will this get fixed?